# SQL count ocurrences on other rows with common field values

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table like

```
datetime                     id        category
 2018-01-01 01:00:00 |      619225 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:15:00 |      619161 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:15:00 |      621510 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:15:00 |      619599 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      618702 | {Robbery}                                                                                                                          |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      618937 | {Assault}                                                                                                                          |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      619199 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      620240 | {Non-Criminal}                                                                                                                     |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      620742 | {"Lost Property"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:30:00 |      621474 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:45:00 |      619192 | {"Larceny Theft"}                                                                                                                  |     1
 2018-01-01 01:45:00 |      618718 | {"Other Offenses"}                                                                                                                 |     1
```

And need to create a query to count the "id" from same "category" on the same "datetime".
For example:

```
2018-01-01 01:15:00 |      619161 | {"Larceny Theft"} |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select datetime, min(id), category, count(*)
from t
group by datetime, category;
```